# ARCore : what is the min SDK version supported ?

Tags: java, android, arcore

It is written on this page :

https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/getting-started

that "Your app's minSDKVersion must be 19 or higher" (Android 4.1)

But it is written in the gradle file of the hello_ar_java project this :

```
 // 24 is the minimum since ARCore only works with 24 and higher.
        minSdkVersion 24
```

What is the real min Android version to use ARCore ?

Thanks.

Comment: API 19 is Android 4.4 :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order to use the ARCore features, you need to use API 24 or greater.  The library itself can be used in 19, but it will gracefully tell you that the device is not supported.  This allows for applications to still work on older versions of Android, but take advantage of ARCore starting with 24.